# /build dir on a Yii2 app (advanced template)

Tags: build, gruntjs, yii2

I'm working on the frontend of a Yii2 app and I want to implement Grunt to perform a small number of tasks like compiling my .sass files and concatenate and minify .js files.

I know I don't need to push the node-modules folder to the repo, anyone who wants it can just `npm install` as I have it packaged properly, so there's no need for my team mates to have the node-modules folder if they don't touch the frontend side of the app whatsoever. My question is, should i push my build folder, where i have my .sass and .js files before they're compiled? Or better yet, I know I don't NEED to push it but should I want it there as a backup in case i want to pull the project from a different computer or so? Is there any downside to having the /build dir on the repo?

I don't want to clutter the repo for everybody else, yet i feel like i should have it there as a backup, or even if someone else wants to edit the files, is this common practice?

Also, to anyone familiar with the yii2 advanced template, where exactly should said /build folder go?

Thank you.

Comment: Compiling your sass files and minifying are both possible via the assetBundles. Are you sure you need a build dir in the first place?

Comment: I am not. Wasn't aware of that. Can you also auto-prefix? I'm going to take a look into the assetBundles! Thank you

Comment: Here's the documentation : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html you should be able to do what you want under section `Asset Conversion` and `Asset Compression`. As for auto-prefixing, it might be out of the box. But if it isn't you should be able to extend `AssetBundle` to do that pretty easily.

Comment: If you need any help I'm more than happy to provide a more in depth answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into it and let you know!